# npm ERR! Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"

Tags: npm-install

While installing no-kafka I got an error. Can anyone help how to fix this issue?

> C:\Kafka-node>npm install no-kafka
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "no-kafka"
>   npm ERR! node v4.2.4
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
>
> npm ERR! Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:".
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Kafka-node\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Below command fixed the issue

set http_proxy=http://registry.npmjs.org/